# Get started with sigma example - unable to get it to work

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, sigma.js

I am trying to get the simple 3 node with 3 edges example from the homepage of http://sigmajs.org/ to work. However, instead of getting started its getting me thwarted...

Given the following index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
  #container {
    max-width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: auto;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container"></div>
<script src="sigma.min.js"></script>
<script src="sigma.parsers.json.min.js"></script>
<script>
  sigma.parsers.json('data.json', {
    container: 'container',
    settings: {
      defaultNodeColor: '#ec5148'
    }
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and the following data.json

```
{
  "nodes": [
    {
      "id": "n0",
      "label": "A node",
      "x": 0,
      "y": 0,
      "size": 3
    },
    {
      "id": "n1",
      "label": "Another node",
      "x": 3,
      "y": 1,
      "size": 2
    },
    {
      "id": "n2",
      "label": "And a last one",
      "x": 1,
      "y": 3,
      "size": 1
    }
  ],
  "edges": [
    {
      "id": "e0",
      "source": "n0",
      "target": "n1"
    },
    {
      "id": "e1",
      "source": "n1",
      "target": "n2"
    },
    {
      "id": "e2",
      "source": "n2",
      "target": "n0"
    }
  ]
}
```

And the most recent version of sigma.min.js and sigma.parsers.json.min.js library taken from https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/releases/download/v1.1.0/release-v1.1.0.zip

And given that the index.html, data.json and the js libraries are all in one directory, the index.html does not display the simple graph in either Chrome, Firefox or IE10.

What am I missing here in order to get the example to work?

Comment: you need the `sigma.parsers.json` not `sigma.parsers.json.min.js`

Comment: Thank you for your answer @john, I have changed the import to 
`<script src="sigma.parsers.json.js"></script>`
and placed the corresponding library in the directory folder based on the version from: https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/blob/master/plugins/sigma.parsers.json/sigma.parsers.json.js 
However, the graph still does not show.

Comment: work for me here a Screenshot ( http://i.imgur.com/UHZAMqX.png ) for result and another Screenshot ( http://i.imgur.com/A9sSYQT.png ) for code

Comment: and i just copy paste your data.json :)

Comment: Again, thank you for answering @john. I am almost embarrased to tell you that... somehow it is still not working for me.

I changed my code to your code with exception of the sigma.min.js src link.

I am getting the following debugging information:
`XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///D:.../data.json. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.` and `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`

Just for my sanity, I am 100% sure the data.json file is in the same folder ;)

Comment: okey i think  i know the problem now, you are using any local servers to server your files, or you just open the index.html ? I am pretty sure you just open the index.html

Comment: I am opening the file locally yes. I tried to make the example Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable so I chose to keep everything local. I should have mentioned this in the Question. I am not using a local server. (the idea is to load the .html in a webview container in a JavaFX stand alone application)

Comment: Okey it will not work if you just open it locally you need to serve it, for example apache or xamp or any other server

Comment: Allright, that clears up alot. Thanks! I do have some other examples with the data hard coded in the .html file. Those files do render the graph. Am I correct in assuming that when I want to use a data.json object and load it into a script I can only achieve this by running it on a server?

Comment: yes  you need to serve your folder check this screenshot from my machine http://i.imgur.com/h0MtKly.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will not render because sigmajs use a `XMLHttpRequest` to parse the file data.json and the web security of chrome and other browsers block `XMLHttpRequest` to local files because it is a security issue.

Comment: Hosting it by local http server may be a solution, like `docker run -it --rm -p 8080:80 --name web -v $(pwd):/usr/share/nginx/html nginx`.